# send and receive .txt file through serial port in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I want to send and receive .txt file and send it frame by frame each frame contain 16 bytes pure data ,length and check-sum
all projects and example in c# that send/receive just text; not file.

Comment: And what doesn't work? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1.You will have to use Some BinaryReader which Reads the File [BinaryReader.ReadBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2.On each 16 bytes read send it via serial Port (You need to properly configure it , this may be tricky)
3.Receive Data via serial Port 
4.Write to new File via [BinaryWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I need code when I write a 16 bytes array  to serial port
that save this array in the same location when it was in the original one, 
and take the other 16 bytes ... etc